# redis: "Multi Bulk Reply" -> lua table

Tags: lua, redis

ti have a sorted-set like this:

```
    |key  |score |member
zadd mykey 100    event:1
zadd mykey 101    event:2
zadd mykey 102    event:3
```

now i use a lua-script to return a sub-set from a given score-range

```
var result = redis.call('zrangebyscore', 'mykey', start, stop, 'WITHSCORES')
```

what would the result-Table look like **in lua-script**? (since i can not debug, i have to ask)

From the [redis-doc](http://redis.io/commands/eval): Redis multi bulk reply -> Lua table (may have other Redis data types nested) - this is all the info i can find.

would it be like:

```
result = { 'event:1', 100, 'event:2', 101, 'event:3', 102 }
```

or like

```
result = { 100, 'event:1', 101, 'event:2', 102, 'event:3' }
```

or different?

Answer (score 2):

The result from a `zrangebyscore ... withscores` -- or any read from a sorted set with scores, really -- will be returned as a lua table looking like this:

```
result = { "event:1", "100", "event:2", "101" }
```

Value first, score second. Values and scores are both strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you are using can write to standard output, you could add a dump function and output the table format.

I use

```
function dump (tt, label,indent, done)
    if debug == true then
       if label == nil then
          label = 'Dump'
       end
        done = done or {}
        indent = indent or 0
        if type(tt) == "table" then
            if indent == 0 then
                io.write(string.rep (" ", indent))
                io.write(label..'\n')
            end
            for key, value in pairs (tt) do
                io.write(string.rep (" ", indent)) -- indent it
                if type (value) == "table" and not done [value] then
                    done [value] = true
                    io.write(string.format("[%s] => table\n", tostring (key)));
                    io.write(string.rep (" ", indent+4)) -- indent it
                    io.write("(\n");
                    dump (value, tostring(key),indent + 7, done)
                    io.write(string.rep (" ", indent+4)) -- indent it
                    io.write(")\n");
                else
                    io.write(string.format("[%s] => %s\n",
                    tostring (key), tostring(value)))
                end
            end
        else
            io.write(tostring(label)..':'..tostring(tt))
        end
    else
        return
    end
end
```

So for your example you would simply add

```
debug = true
dump(var,'redis-table')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `io` module is not available. There is `redis.log` and the following libraries: base, table, string, math, debug, cjson, cmsgpack.

Comment: Looking at the help for redis, it should be possible to replace io.write with redis.log(redis.LOG_VERBOSE,value).  Although the result will not be so well formatted

Comment: It might be even easier to `redis.log(redis.LOG_VERBOSE, cjson.encode(result))`... But it doesn't matter, because the answer is below. But the asker seems to have abandoned us. ;)